# What's the difference between have/has been and was?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, differences, word-usage

English is my second language and I have always been confused with 'have been/has been' and the idea that it could be replaced with 'was' in some contexts.

For instance, this is a part of an urgent email about a bomb threat:

> An unconfirmed bomb threat has been received. The halls are being evacuated. More info to follow.

My doubt is: why couldn't it be 'was received' and what that would change?

Another example:

> The thumbnails base has been updated.

Many times, I see 'have/has been' in something that could be 'was' from my understanding.

This is a question I have been asking myself for a long time.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had/has/have been is usually used for something that was done in the past and still applies (multiple events).

Was/were usually applies to something done in the past that no longer applies (single event).

for the complete explanation, please visit this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-was-and-had-been).

hope that answer ur question

Comment: Please don't answer questions that should be on [ell.se].

Comment: oke, sorry for my fault.